# Is it possible to simulate MetricKit payload in Xamarin or Maui app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, metrickit

I'm trying to avoid waiting the full 24 hours for MetricKit payloads to arrive in my application for better testing.  I see XCode provides a debug option to Simulate MetricKit Payloads but naturally that isn't available for us.

Is there a good way to mimic this behavior through Visual Studio for Mac / Code on a Xamarin or Maui application?

Comment: have you tried running the tool while your app is running?

Comment: Do you mean the Simulate MetricKit Payload debug menu item in xcode?  This is grayed out as our app is deployed and debugged through visual studio.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I thought it might work if any iOS device was connected